# Array, avoid pulling Duplicates, simple code, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates, draw

Its a card game, I draw 2 cards from the deck (the array) with the help of two functions.

Each element of the array represent one card with a symbol Spades, Hearts, Diamonds or Clubs.

These numbers in the array \5 \4 \3 \6, represent Clubs, Dimaond, Heatrs, spades (just if ur curious)

**The problem!**

When I draw a card two times I sometimes get Duplicates.. The same card twice.

How do I make sure the same card cant be drawn twice?
How do I avoid getting duplicates??

This is how the code Looks like.

Some INFO about the array...
The further in, in the array, the higher value the element has.
I have shortened the array... for easy testing of a solution... later the array will be 52 elements.

```
array<string, 3> cards = { "Ess \5", "Ess \4", "Ess \3" };


//The function.
pair<string, int> draw_card()
{
    int random_index = rand() % 52;
    string card = cards[random_index];
    return { card, random_index };
}

int main()
{
// Seed, random.
 srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));



// Calling the function 2 times.
    pair<string, int> you_drew = draw_card();
    cout << "You drew: " << you_drew.first << endl;

    pair<string, int> comp_drew = draw_card();
    cout << "Computer drew: " << comp_drew.first << endl;



// Deciding the winner.
    int your_score{ 0 };
    int the_computers_score{ 0 };

    if (you_drew.second > comp_drew.second) {
        cout << "You Won!" << endl;
        your_score++;
    }
    else if (you_drew.second < comp_drew.second) {
        cout << "You Lost!" << endl;
        the_computers_score++;
    }

        return 0;
   }
```

Everything is working fine, EXCEPT sometimes I get duplicates... I want to make sure I can Not get that...
Somehow when I draw a card the element in the array should not be able to be drawn.. I want to avoid getting duplicates. Please help me!

Shouldnt something like this work? its not but.. shouldnt it?

```
pair<string, int> comp_drew = draw_card();

        if (you_drew == comp_drew) {
            bool run8 = true;
            while (run8) {
                pair<string, int> comp_drew = draw_card();


                if (comp_drew != you_drew) {
                     cout << "Computer drew: " << comp_drew.first << endl;
                    run8 = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

Or maybe another solution..
Perhaps after calling the function one time i can delete the return index from the array?

Comment: Some general ideas. You could change `array` to `vector` and erase each element after you draw it. Also take a look at `std::shuffle` which can be used to just iterate through the `vector` once you shuffle it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Im studying programming and the task is to use an array.. I will look at shuffle. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the drawn card to the end and only choose an index smaller than 51 the next time.

```
int array_len = 52; // global variables are not great, but it's easier here
pair<string, int> draw_card()
{
    int random_index = rand() % array_len;
    --array_len;
    string card = cards[random_index];
    std::swap(cards[random_index], cards[array_len]);
    
    return { card, random_index };
}
```

Comment: Thank you n314159. Now I dont get a duplicate value. But the comparision, the deciding a winner isnt working now... Now sometimes the end of my code (the deciding a winner) cant decide a winner.. its blank..

Comment: I answered my own question to highlight the problem with this solution.

Comment: @user904963 The length of the array does implicitly change since we do not want to use the last card anymore. There is a difference between calling this method the first and the second time.

Comment: @gunnar20008 I missed that you use the index to compare the two cards. That will break when you get the same random number twice in a row. This is the only way that can happen. In your case you can just add the equality-case to the "You lost" branch. Since if you twice get the same number, the second time you will have drawn the initally highest card. This will break if you try to call the thing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this.

**std::random_shuffle**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class CardMachine {
    static unsigned constexpr DECK_SIZE = 4;
    int cards[DECK_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4};
    int lastUsedCardIndex = -1;
public:
    int getCard() {
        if (lastUsedCardIndex == DECK_SIZE - 1)
            shuffle();
        return cards[++lastUsedCardIndex];
    }
    
    void shuffle() {
        random_shuffle(begin(cards), end(cards));
    }
};

int main()
{
    CardMachine cardMachine = CardMachine();
    
    cout << "unhsuffled - 1,2,3,4 without duplicates:" << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    
    cout << "Shuffled. Random order, and still no duplicates:" << endl;
    cardMachine.shuffle(); // or call getCard which can shuffle
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Mark Card as Taken**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class CardMachine {
    static unsigned constexpr DECK_SIZE = 4;
    inline static int constexpr cards[DECK_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4};
    bool cardIsGone[DECK_SIZE] = {false, false, false, false};
public:
    int getCard() {
        while(true) {
            int const RANDOM_INDEX = rand()%DECK_SIZE;
            if(!cardIsGone[RANDOM_INDEX]) {
                cardIsGone[RANDOM_INDEX] = true;
                return cards[RANDOM_INDEX];
            }
        }
    }
    
    void shuffle() {
        for(bool &isGone : cardIsGone)
            isGone = false;
        lastUsedCardIndex = -1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CardMachine cardMachine = CardMachine();
    
    cout << "Shuffled - Random order, and still no duplicates:" << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    
    cout << "Shuffled. Random order, and still no duplicates:" << endl;
    cardMachine.shuffle(); // Causes infinite loop if you call getCard DECK_SIZE + 1 times
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It's not the most efficient solution, but with small values like 52, it should be instant.

**Swap Used Cards to Back and Keep Track of Range**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class CardMachine {
    static unsigned constexpr DECK_SIZE = 4;
    int cards[DECK_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4};
    int lastCardIndexExlusive = DECK_SIZE;
public:
    int getCard() {
        int const RANDOM_INDEX = rand()%lastCardIndexExlusive;
        swap(cards[RANDOM_INDEX],cards[lastCardIndexExlusive - 1]);
        return cards[--lastCardIndexExlusive];
    }
    
    void shuffle() {
        lastCardIndexExlusive = DECK_SIZE;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CardMachine cardMachine = CardMachine();
    
    cout << "Shuffled - Random order, and still no duplicates:" << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    
    cout << "Shuffled. Random order, and still no duplicates:" << endl;
    cardMachine.shuffle(); // Causes exception if getCard DECK_SIZE + 1 times
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Remember Last Card**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class CardMachine {
    static unsigned constexpr DECK_SIZE = 4;
    int cards[DECK_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4};
    int lastCard = -1;
public:
    int getCard() {
        int const RANDOM_INDEX = rand()%DECK_SIZE;
        if (lastCard == RANDOM_INDEX) {
            return getCard();
        }
        lastCard = cards[RANDOM_INDEX];
        return lastCard;
    }
    
    void shuffle() {
        lastCard = -1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CardMachine cardMachine = CardMachine();
    
    cout << "Shuffled - Random order, and still no duplicates, but only able to produce 2:" << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;

    cout << "Shuffled. Random order, and still no duplicates:" << endl;
    cardMachine.shuffle(); // Causes potential duplicates if getCards 3+ times
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;
    cout << cardMachine.getCard() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

All of these solutions make use of a class to hold state for use in `getCard` to make sure we get the right behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are an angel, but this is a little too complicated for me.. i havent even learned about classes yet.. will you take a look at my answer to my post. I have updated my code. Its working in giving me a random value, as i want, but another problem came up.. The deciding a winner... which I think has something to do with im shortening the array.. thank you.

Comment: @gunnar20008 A class gives an abstraction that hides unnecessary details from the user of the class. Here, the user (you, even though you're writing both main and the card class) only needs to understand that `getCard` will return non-duplicate cards if called correctly (e.g. with preceding calls to `shuffle` when needed). If you want to do this type of thing with plain functions that have no associated data/state, you can create global variables to hold state. For example, in the last option, you can declare `int lastCard = -1` outside your function as well as `cards` and `DECK_SIZE`.

Comment: @gunnar20008 I would declare that global state/data right above the function(s) that use it as global state has the problem of anyone anywhere being able to access or, if it's not `const`, change it. Putting the data nearby the functions will reduce the chance of users of your code accidentally using it or being confused about why it exists. You might have `unsigned const DECK_SIZE = 4; int cards[DECK_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4}; int lastCardIndexExclusive = DECK_SIZE;  int getCard() {...} void shuffl() {...}` with appropriate newlines (If you were to use the second-to-last solution).